# Correção na apresentação da barra de status criada com o plugin Airline

Tags: linux, vim

Instalei o plugin [**Airline**](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline) com o objetivo de ter uma barra de status personalizada no meu editor, conforme visto na figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No entanto, a barra de status do meu editor está apresentando os símbolos <, >> e <. Como corrigir este problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resolução do problema relatado consiste em baixar as fontes do projeto [Powerline](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) e instalá-las no sistema, pois as fontes deste projeto fornecem símbolos customizados. Vamos aos passos:

## Donwload das fontes

Primeiramente, faça o download das fontes. Estas podem ser obtidas a partir do link do projeto, no [github](https://github.com/powerline/fonts/archive/master.zip) ou a partir do comando:

```
git clone https://github.com/powerline/fonts.git
```

## Instalação

Após a obtenção do pacote de fontes, você deve executar o arquivo `.install` para que ele faça a instalação destas. Será criado o diretório `~/.fonts`, caso este não exista. Este diretório é usado no linux para a instalação de fontes.

## Configuração do terminal

Altere o tipo de fonte usado em seu terminal de comandos. No caso de utilização do gnome-terminal, você vai em **Editar > Preferências do perfil** e edite o tipo de fonte para uma das fontes Powerline. No meu caso, escolhi a fonte **Meslo LG S Regular for Powerline**.

## Resultado

O resultado é uma barra de status mais elegante, mais útil, que permite a identificação mais rápida dos modos de edição usados no momento da edição do texto, dando possibilidade ao aumento de produtividade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Referências

https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3359/how-to-fix-status-bar-symbols-in-airline-plugin